# copy data from one table to another in oracle - not working

Tags: oracle

Am executing the below query and it results in an error.

```
insert into me.attr ( EXPS)
 values( select EXPS from mine.attr 
          where fiscal_year=2012 
          and accounting_period=11 
          and gaap_cd='ZA' );


 Error: insert into me.attr ( EXPS) values ( select EXPS from mine.attr
 where fiscal_year=2012 and accounting_period=11 and gaap_cd='ZA' )
 Error at Command Line:31 Column:2 
 Error report:
 SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
 *Cause:    
 *Action:
```

Can someone please help me on the issue.

Comment: What do the tables look like?

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `select` within an `insert`, you do not use the `values` clause: Try this:

```
insert into 
  me.attr ( EXPS) 
  select EXPS 
    from mine.attr 
    where fiscal_year=2012 and 
          accounting_period=11 and 
          gaap_cd='ZA'
```

Comment: Thank you and if i need to copy the data from one database to another?

Comment: Hi, I used the above mentioned syntax but the query failed with the below error.

SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 
00942. 00000 - "table or view does not exist"